# how to query array within an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

When I execute a `print_r` I get this result...

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [A_program_id] => a0F36000008PIYF
        [XC_program_logo] => louisville.jpg
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [A_program_id] =>  a0F36000008qjSp
        [XC_program_logo] => alabama.jpg
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [A_program_id] => a0F36000008pRxL
        [XC_program_logo] => trinity.jpg
    )
)
```

How do I make a while loop or whatever to properly fetch needed to query something like this:

```
//zero based
echo"".$rows[0][0]."</td><td>"".$rows[1][0].""</td><td>"".$rows[2][0]."";
echo"".$rows[0][1]."</td><td>"".$rows[1][1].""</td><td>"".$rows[2][1]."";
```

to show

```
louisville.jpg      alabama.jpg       trinity.jpg
a0F36000008PIYF     a0F36000008qjSp   a0F36000008pRxL
```

please help thx

Comment: The easiest way is [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column) to extract each rows data from the source, and then [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to add the `</td><td>` between each value:

```
echo implode('</td><td>', array_column($rows, 'XC_program_logo'));
echo implode('</td><td>', array_column($rows, 'A_program_id'));
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/o5PIa)

This will give the same output as the two `echo` statements in your question.